# Why is the byte size different for a variable that contains 1472 byte of a file

Tags: python

If I have a file say a img, and I try to divide the file into 14xx byte chunks by reading 1 byte at a time through a generator and join them together in a variable, why is the resulting variable not 14xx byte? Is it because of the internal handling of the variable in python? If so what are some possible way to test if I actually have a 14xx data besides having my create_data function return another indicator?

```
def split_file(self, filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            byte = f.read(1)
            if not byte:
                break
            yield(byte)


def create_data(self):
    for x in range (1, 1472):
        next_byte = split_file.filename

        if not next_byte :
            break
        else: 
            msg = msg + split_file(self.filename)
    return msg

curr_data = self.create_data
    while sys.getsizeof(curr_data) == 1472: 
        # do something with curr_data
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `range(1,1472)` gives you 1471 elements. The end index of range is not included. I strongly recommend you get in the habit of using zero-based ranges: `range(1472)` is 1472 elements.

Comment: Aside: why read a file in increments of one byte? Seems pretty inefficient to me.

Comment: @millimoose I wasn't sure if f.read(1472) will throw exception if file size is not divisible by 1472, relatively new to python here, also I caring more about correctness right now than efficiency

Comment: @user1433153 In pretty much every I/O system that's based on the C standard library, it means "read **up to** 1472 bytes, and return the number of bytes read". (Or, in the case of Python, a byte array with only the bytes read.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `len()`, not `sys.getsizeof()`. `sys.getsizeof()` includes the overhead of Python objects. You will also notice it gives "odd" behavior (i.e., probably not what you expect) on containers such as lists: it counts the memory used by the container, but not by the objects inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to use a generator that actually reads the file chunks in the size you wish:

```
def split_file(self, filename, size=1472):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            buf= f.read(size)
            if not buf:
                break
            yield(buf)
```

If you do it this way, you do not need to do 1472 calls to `split_file` and 1472 string appends in `create_data` that you currently have.

Then you can do:

```
for chunk in split_file(self.filename, self.size):
    # if you want to discard the last chunk if len is less than size:
    if len(chunk)<self.size:
        break

    #otherwise, deal with a chunk:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In these kinds of situations, I just use a function called `super_len`, it works with everything, I get it from requests's `utils.py` file:

```
def super_len(o):
    if hasattr(o, '__len__'):
        return len(o)

    if hasattr(o, 'len'):
        return o.len

    if hasattr(o, 'fileno'):
        try:
            fileno = o.fileno()
        except io.UnsupportedOperation:
            pass
        else:
            return os.fstat(fileno).st_size

    if hasattr(o, 'getvalue'):
        # e.g. BytesIO, cStringIO.StringI
        return len(o.getvalue())
```

As kindall states, you need to use `len` instead of `sys.getsizeof`. `super_len` works in all cases that I've encountered.